5 times, 9 times, 10 times, etc. multiplication table?
I am wondering what's the most natural way of saying ''the five/nine/ten etc. times multiplication table''
The kids had to learn the five times multiplication table today.
The kids had to learn the ten times multiplication table today.
Also, is multiplication table used in the plural or singular form when speaking in general terms?
It is expected that you the multiplication table(s) well.

Again, where is your research?

Amplifying @Lambie’s comment, what do you think the answer might be, and based on what evidence? If the sources you’ve consulted don’t satisfy you, then what is it about them that accounts for their shortfall? How is your question different from the information that those sources provide?

"Times" means "multiplied by" so there is redundancy in the OP's suggestion. You could say "The kids were taught the five times table today." I changed the tone too, from under duress to receptive.

Why is research needed in this case? I really don't get it. I just want to know the most natural way of saying it. That's it. You guys make everything unnecessarily more complicated and everything needs to be pried out you. Why can't you just give a straightforward answer?

The word "multiplication" is far too big for the kids learning their five times table. And all adults know that's how we identify any specific table (without the word "multiplication"). When referring to them collectively, we usually just stick to asking the child "Do you know your times tables?"

@Idk29 I didn't complicate it. Perhaps my earlier comment was too simple. five times table.

And it's the same with all the other numbers? six times table, ten times table, four times table, etc.

Why should the phrasing vary with the multiplier?

Is it the same or not?

It would help if we had something of a bigger picture here.  So you've asked about maths education.  Real estate terms for studios, "meddler/busybody",   porch/mudroom,  spool/reel.....  There's no thread or learning.  Everything is scattered. ....  So please give us the back story; why did you start thinking about times tables today?  Why were you thinking about apartments? Where did you find the term "multiplication table"?  Is there some source?  a textbook?  How are you going to use this knowledge?  Try to interact with the forum, and you'll get a lot less negativity.  Be positive

Example: first google hit: https://www.timestables.com/


"The kids had to learn the five times table."

No need for the word "multipication".  It's the same with other numbers.
Singular for one table.  Multiple for all the tables. That's just normal rules for singular and plural.
You can use "multiplication table(s)" without a number in more adult context.

Children should know the multiplication table (or tables) by the age of ten.

But not "five times multiplication table"

Yes, but all of them together are multiplication tables, a long term.
